# Selecting records from shape that do not match another table's values using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select, table, intersect

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

I have a shapefile that results from an Intersect between a polygon shp and a point shp. So my resulting shp is a point one! One of the field in my intersect resulting shp is "species_names" (let's call it shp.spcNames). And I've got a CSV table imported to my GDD that contains only 1 column with over 600 text record (let's call it tbl.spcNames).

Now, I want to create a shapefile that contains only records in which shp.spcNames is different from all tbl.spcNames. In the end I want to have a point shapefile that contains all the info from my initial intersect shapefile minus the records in which shp.spcNames are present in my table's tbl.spcNames field.

How do I do that?

Comment: How about doing a table join between the intersect layer and the CSV. Then select all points that have NULL in the join field and export them to a new layer.

Comment: @csk I'll try that right now!

Comment: If it works feel free to self-answer. I don't know arc products well enough to write a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all effects the logic steps suggested by @csk, seems to have worked! I still have a lot to do though. But for the purpose of the question I may consider it closed. don't know if I've got to check 'resolved' somewhere ...